# Conditionally deleting rows in MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, sql-delete

I've got a database that is updated regularly by inserting new data. After this update every row with a `timestamp` older than the current `timestamp` is deleted. Like this:

`DELETE FROM myTable WHERE timestamp < ?` where `?` is the current `timestamp`

Now I would like to extend this statement so that it only removes the old rows if there actually are new rows with a `timestamp >= ?`. Is it possible to do such a conditional deletion in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```sql
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE timestamp < ?
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT 1
    FROM myTable
    WHERE timestamp >= ? 
  ) t
)
```

The additional nesting `(SELECT * FROM (...) t)` is required because in MySQL (until 8.0.19, at least), otherwise, you'd get an error:

> You can't specify target table 'myTable' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. What does the single `t` at the end of the statement do?

Comment: @herhuf: In MySQL, all derived tables (subqueries in the `FROM` clause) need a name. It doesn't do anything and isn't really needed here, but it's a basic syntax requirement of MySQL (and other SQL dialects). Try removing it, and you'll see the error message.